# SQL Multiplying DECIMAL(18,4) by DECIMAL(3,2) return DECIMAL(18,4)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have seen a lot of posts with people have similar issues but I've tried all their solutions and none have worked for me. Hopefully you guys can point out the error of my ways..

**SQL**

```
SELECT
    --Raw Values
    Hours, --RESULT: 24.0000
    StartStops, --RESULT: 0.0000

    --Equation without CAST/ROUND
    ((Hours * 1.00)) AS "WhatIf Hours", --RESULT: 24.000000
    ((StartStops * 1.00)) AS "WhatIf Starts", --RESULT: 0.000000

    --CAST output of equation
    CAST((Hours * 1.00) as DECIMAL(18,4)) AS "WhatIf Hours", --RESULT: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
    CAST((StartStops * 1.00) as DECIMAL(18,4)) AS "WhatIf Starts", --RESULT: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

    --CAST each input of equation
    CAST(Hours as DECIMAL(18,4)) * CAST(1.00 as decimal(18,4)) AS "WhatIf Hours", --RESULT: 24.00000000
    CAST(StartStops as DECIMAL(18,4)) * CAST(1.00 AS decimal(18,4)) AS "WhatIf Starts", --RESULT: 0.00000000

    --ROUND output of equation
    ROUND((Hours * 1.00), 4) AS "WhatIf Hours", --RESULT: 24.000000
    ROUND((StartStops * 1.00), 4) AS "WhatIf Starts" --RESULT: 0.000000
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   ID = 1
```

The desired result would be the output of the arithmetic to be `DECIMAL(18,4)` because that is the type of column I will be updating with the value. Can any assist with this?

**UPDATE: CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
   [ID] [int] NOT NULL, 
   [Hours] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
   [StartStops] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
   [Updated] [datetime] NULL,
   [UpdatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,  
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's a picture so you guys know I'm not crazy.

[image]

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53ae9/1)

Comment: what is the data type of `hours` and `startstops` columns?

Comment: Create table has been added

Comment: Why aren't you casting everything as DECIMAL(18,4) in your query?   If you already tried that, what happened?

Comment: See the 6th line of the  query. I tried casting the output of the arithmetic and I get an overflow error. Do you mean cast each piece of the equation?

Comment: What about just `Hours * 1`?

Comment: Not sure why you would get arithmetic overflow. When I run `declare @num decimal(18,4) = 24.0000
select cast((@num * 1.00) as decimal(18,4))` in SQLServer 2008 I get `24.0000`

Comment: @Samcd `Hours * 1` does output `24.0000` which is desired format but `1` will not always be the multiplier. For instance, it could be `.9` which outputs `21.60000` (5 decimal places).

Comment: I can not reproduce. 1) Your create. 2) `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID,Hours,StartStops,Updated,UpdatedBy)VALUES(1,24.0,0,GETDATE(),'')` 3) Your select. If the problem is with different multipliers, give us an example that fails.

Comment: And please try getting it to fail on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) or a similar service. It helps a lot when people can play a bit with your queries and see for themselves what fails and what doesn't.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Is the value of Hours/StartsStops in you `MyTable` equal to `24.0` or `24.0000'?

Comment: I used your create statement. The stored value will be the decimal(18, 4) version of the number 24,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem could be in your settings. See the following example:

Running:

`SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON
declare @num decimal(18,4) = 24.0000
select cast((@num * 1.00) as decimal(18,4))`

results in `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric`. However, running

`SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
declare @num decimal(18,4) = 24.0000
select cast((@num * 1.00) as decimal(18,4))`

gives `24.0000`

According to official MSN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188791.aspx), you can run the following code:

`DECLARE @NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';
IF ( (8192 & @@OPTIONS) = 8192 ) SET @NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT = 'ON';
SELECT @NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT AS NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT;`

to check your system settings.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 CAST((ROUND(Hours * 1.00, 4)) as DECIMAL(18,4)) AS "WhatIf Hours"
```

you are getting the arithmetic overflow because you are trying to convert a decimal with 6 decimal places into one with 4. Rounding it to 4 places first SHOULD do the trick

you could also do

```
CAST((CAST(Hours as DECIMAL(18,4)) * CAST(1.00 as DECIMAL(18,4))) as DECIMAL(18,4))
```